# Impossible to defragment and resize a partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, defragment

I'm trying to shrink the main partition on my new PC with Windows 7 64-bit preloaded from 500 GB to 100 GB.

Unfortunately, some files prevent any attempt to go below 290 GB.

[image]

I have already disabled restore points, as somebody had suggested, but nothing changes.
What do I have to do to further shrink this partition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NTFS has some additional, hidden metadata it usually puts around the middle of a partition. It, in my experience, can't be moved around except by some proprietary software.

The now-defunct Partition Magic could move the MFT around, and a quick search shows that [this](http://www.perfectdisk.com/products/home-perfectdisk11-home-premium/learn-more) may be able to move it around, too. There's a trial version available, so perhaps that might work.

There's also [MyDefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com/), a *highly* configurable disk defragmenter app that provides some facilities for defragmenting the MFT. In my experience, I could not succeed in getting it to move all of the metadata preventing my resize, but perhaps it'll work for you.

Having dealt with this hassle before, though, I would strongly advise that you consider backing up this partition's data and re-creating it anew, if only to save time and many a headache.

Comment: ok, I followed your suggestion and recreated the partition.

Comment: +1 - sometimes the easiest solution is just to do what you know works - backup, reformat, restore.

Answer (score 0):

If your pagefile is on C:, then perhaps disable or move it to the different drive (at least until you're done defragging and resizing).

You can also try out [GPartEd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) for resizing and moving the partitions around, it's free.

As Dylan mentioned in his answer, a backup is always a good idea when moving/changing partitions. :)